# JSON.NET won't deserialize into my object, throws an exception

Tags: c#, json.net

My JSON (myString) looks like this:

```
"http://d.opencalais.com/dochash-1/0701d73f-2f99-39e1-8c29-e61ee8bf3238/cat/1":
{
  "_typeGroup": "topics",
  "category": "http://d.opencalais.com/cat/Calais/Law_Crime",
  "classifierName": "Calais",
  "categoryName": "Law_Crime",
  "score": 0.869
}
```

I am trying to deserialise the above exact string into an object:

```
public class OpenCalaisResult
{
    public string _typeGroup {get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string categoryName { get; set; }
    public string classifierName { get; set; }
    public decimal score { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying this code:

```
OpenCalaisResult myObject = (OpenCalaisResult)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myString, typeof(OpenCalaisResult), settings);
```

I get an exception:

> {"Error converting value
>   \"http://d.opencalais.com/dochash-1/0701d73f-2f99-39e1-8c29-e61ee8bf3238/cat/1\"
>   to type 'MyApp.Parsers.JsonTypes.OpenCalaisResult'. Path
>   '', line 1, position 78."}

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: your json is incorrectly formatted.  I'm not good at json either so I use http://jsonlint.com/ to ensure it's valid.

Comment: I think you've cracked it, even though I am taking the JProperty and converting it to a JSON string, it's not actually valid JSON because it is missing the { and }. How stupid that the method to convert it to JSON would forget these. I added them manually and it seems to work now. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception now, but my object comes back with all fields as NULL. Still not quite fixed :(

Comment: I have solved it, by doing .Children().First().ToString() on the object. Also I don't need to add the { } myself if I do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your json should be like this

```
 {
 "http://d.opencalais.com/dochash-1/0701d73f-2f99-39e1-8c29-e61ee8bf3238/cat/1":
  {
    "_typeGroup": "topics",
    "category": "http://d.opencalais.com/cat/Calais/Law_Crime",
    "classifierName": "Calais",
    "categoryName": "Law_Crime",
    "score": 0.869
   }
  }
```

Comment: You're right, in the end, the solution was to do .Children.First() on the above JSON, which gave me `{ "_typeGroup": "topics", .... }` without the top part, and it parsed perfectly into my object. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.json.org/

Shows objects have the form ...

{ ... }

The form of your JSON is ...

x : { ... }

I'm guessing that 'x' is the type of the class being [de]serialised ... I don't believe it's supported by your library.

JSON support is a bit random.